# How to injection a service in orchard 1.10.1?

Tags: service, orchardcms, autofac, code-injection

I want custom UserNamePasswordValidator in my orchard project.
Like this,How can i injection IUserService?  thank you.

```
    public class CustomUserNameValidator: UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    private IUserSevice m_UserService;

    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (null == userName || null == password)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        if(!m_UserService.CheckUser(userName,password))
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Password");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an excellent article in the docs about [dependency injection](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/How-Orchard-works/#dependency-injection).

You basically need to build and implement an interface like this:

`public interface ICustomUserNameValidator : IDependency{}`

Afterwards you can inject it wherever you want.

```
public class MyPartDriver : ContentPartDriver
{
  public MyPartDriver(ICustomerUserNameValidator validator)
  {
  }
}
```